# Another one of those odd sequence puzzles

Tags: mathematics, number-sequence

This is an interesting one.
I will do the same thing that I usually do.
After one week, a hint. After 2 weeks, a hint. After 3 weeks, an answer.

I may change this system.

What number goes in the question mark, and why does it go there?

> 0,0,1,2,3,1,3,2,3,3,4,2,4,4,3,3,4,4,5,3,5,4,5,3,5,5,4,4,5,?

HINT:

> There is a inputting function that each number is put into... when you undo that function, you get a simple sequence.

HINT 2:

> If you take this inputting function onto 24862486 you get 4. I will take the next three requests of inputting from the comments.

HINT 3:

> This has to do with prime factors.

HINT 4:

> It requires the repeated use of a single function.

HINT 5:

> This function is related to the Greatest Prime Factor

Comment: Is it something to do with the _word_ for each number?

Comment: @randal'thor No it is not.

Comment: may be answer is 5?

Comment: @ It might be; I promise there is a perfect reasoning.

Comment: To clarify hint 1, are the numbers we are given put into the input function, or are they the result?

Comment: @AggieKidd They are the result.

Comment: You said you'd post the answer after 3 weeks.....

Comment: @ghosts_in_the_code I did, but this question has had sooo little activity... it seems pointless.

Comment: @awesomepi So either you could put a bounty to attract attention, or just post the answer.

Comment: can you give me the values for inputs 8 , 29862968, 191199 . ( you said you ll pick from the comments right? )

Comment: Would you call this sequence relevant?
1,2,2,3,2,4,2,4,3,4,2,6,2,4,4,5

Comment: @Imprfectluck 2,4,5

Comment: Can we assume that the number sequence you put in to get these results is the list of positive integers? 1, 2, 3, 4, etc.? It does line up that `a(8) = 2`

Comment: @EngineerToast No, you cannot... but the sequence is relatively simple

Comment: @EngineerToast But 8 IS in there.

Comment: 5May-25March=1Month 11 days

Comment: Can you give me the values for 1, 3, 5 ?

Comment: @Mathsman100 0,2,3

Comment: @Imprfectluck I just realized... I'm sorry, 8 actually goes to 1

Comment: I cracked what sequence, just need to know the input function!

Comment: Hint on Function?

Comment: Does 917 give 4?

Comment: If yes, then I know the answer.

Comment: @Mathsman100 Please avoid to split your comments. If you want to add something to your last comment, edit it!

Comment: Since 1 maps to 0, does the function feature a log of the input?

Comment: @LogicianWithAHat , no it cannot be log(at least not only log, it must have other complex mathematics ).

Comment: Agreed - there seems to be some kind of periodic function to it. I just suggested log as it reduces the larger numbers very effectively

Comment: Just as some information for you, awesomepi, bounty questions are not the only questions that get attention here, as I have noticed there are very few unanswered questions here. Try making it more interesting, give it a new and better title(if possible) , add some flavor text to it  (maybe a story), and give more interesting hints.

Comment: Since we never get to 6, could we by chance be using mod 6 anywhere?

Comment: @AggieKidd The numbers just never got big enough to get to 6.

Comment: does it have a relation to discrete logarithm?

Comment: @Azad No, it does not.

Comment: @awesomepi The question is getting _pretty_ old now, so could you please post an answer (or atleast give another hint) ?

Comment: @Mathsman100 I will post 2 hints

Comment: Does the function used require any sort of rounding/floor/ceiling, or does it always, naturally, produce integer outputs for integer inputs?

Comment: @tfitzger It always produces integer outputs. You cannot input a non-integer input.

Comment: Can your function produce arbitrarily large outputs?

Comment: @2012rcampion Yes it can.

Comment: What would be the result if we input 7?

Comment: @AggieKidd It would be 2.

Comment: It's been more than 9 weeks. Isn't it time to post the solution?

Comment: @r.e.s. It is... I will post it when I get on my computer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a Haskell implementation of the answer:

```
import Data.Numbers.Primes

seqFun 1 = 0
seqFun input = recWhile input 0
    where
      recWhile a n = res
          where
            pfs = primeFactors a
            modN = n+1
            maxPF = maximum pfs
            res
                | a < 2 = modN
                | maxPF == 2 = modN
                | otherwise = recWhile (maxPF + 1) modN

fibs = 1:1:(zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs))
thirtyFibs = take 30 fibs
main = print $ map seqFun thirtyFibs
```

Just run `main` to see the entire sequence.

Note that many of the hints were not true; the function is not related to the Greatest Common Factor, and the hints for 29862968 and 191199 were incorrect.

For fun, here's a much shorter version:

```
import Data.Numbers.Primes
seqFun = length . takeWhile (>3) . iterate (succ.maximum.primeFactors)
fibs = 1:1:(zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs))
main = print $ map seqFun (take 30 fibs)
```

This version doesn't work for 2 or 3, though.

Comment: I'm sorry, this was a poorly written question. On the Greatest Common Factor, I meant to write "Greatest Prime Factor"

Comment: No worries! I had fun working with it, trying to combine primeFactors, gcd, and other functions and feeling like I was getting closer.

Comment: How about an English language version of the answer.

Comment: Certainly! http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/15810/12927 I prefer the code version since I can easily test lots of numbers with it.

Answer (score 3):

As an extension to MisterEman22's "what we know so far," hint #4 specifies that the function has to do with prime factors, so I added the prime factorization of each input to the table, in case it helps someone else.

```
       1                    1   0
       2                    2   1
       8                2*2*2   1
       3                    3   2
       7                    7   2
      21                  3*7   2
     144          2*2*2*2*3*3   2
       5                    5   3
      13                   13   3
      34                 2*17   3
      55                 5*11   3
     610               2*5*61   3
     987               3*7*47   3
    6765            3*5*11*41   3
   46368   2*2*2*2*2*3*3*7*23   3
      89                   89   4
     233                  233   4
     377                13*29   4
    1597                 1597   4
    2584          2*2*2*17*19   4
   17711               89*199   4
  196418          2*17*53*109   4
  317811          3*13*29*281   4
24862486      2*11*73*113*137   4
    4181               37*113   5
   10946             2*13*421   5
   28657                28657   5
   75025             5*5*3001   5
  121393              233*521   5
  191199          3*17*23*163   5
  514229               514229   5
```

Note I also sorted by output value, to aid in any pattern-finding.

My guess is that the number has to do with the number of applications of a function before it reaches some final value (1).

Answer (score 2):

**Here's what we know so far**

The number we are looking for is whatever 832040 maps to. The function is keeping the output values low, but as the input gets increasingly larger, the output is getting slightly larger

Here is a listing of what all the other terms before it are to help you out, based on the Fibonacci sequence:

> 1= 0
>
> 1= 0
>
> 2= 1
>
> 3= 2
>
> 5= 3
>
> 8= 1
>
> 13= 3
>
> 21= 2
>
> 34= 3
>
> 55= 3
>
> 89= 4
>
> 144= 2
>
> 233= 4
>
> 377= 4
>
> 610= 3
>
> 987= 3
>
> 1597= 4
>
> 2584= 4
>
> 4181= 5
>
> 6765= 3
>
> 10946= 5
>
> 17711= 4
>
> 28657= 5
>
> 46368= 3
>
> 75025= 5
>
> 121393= 5
>
> 196418= 4
>
> 317811= 4
>
> 514229= 5
>
> 832040= ?

And here's the non-Fibonacci numbers that he gave us:

> 24862486= 4
>
> 29862968= 4
>
> 191199= 5

Comment: We also know that 191199 maps to 5, which means that numbers that aren't in the Fib sequence can be put into this function without error (more generally meaning that the function likely has nothing to do with the Fib sequence itself).

Comment: @BaileyM Good note. I'll edit this and add in the other numbers that he gave us as well

Comment: @MisterEman22 The 29862986 was NOT a mistype

Comment: @awesomepi - You've just mentioned a *third* eight-digit number (previously we had $24862468\to 4$ and $29862968\to 4$, and in the preceding comment you mention $29862986$). Are you saying that all three of these give $4$?

Comment: Well crap it is a mistype... I changed it to 24862486. And the 29862986 was also a mistype. I meant to say 29862968

Comment: @MisterEman I per edited the question to fix it: can you accept it?

Answer (score 0):

The inputting sequence is the [Fibonacci Series](https://www.mathsisfun.com/numbers/fibonacci-sequence.html) (1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21......).
The function, I don't know.

Comment: Nope. 233 gives 4, while 8 gives 1. Must be something else.

Comment: Also, 2584 gives 4, while 75025 gives 5, but they both sum to 19

Comment: It is the Fibonacci Series though...

Comment: @VicAche you are right, it is not sum of numbers, and BTW, I found out it was Fibonacci series by seeing the first two numbers were 0's.

Comment: Yeah, I had come to the same conclusions about fibonacci. I knew it was an ascending sequence, and there are few well known ascending sequences that start by two peculiar, identical terms

Comment: You should have written it in an answer then, it would have saved me time to go through as many sequences as possible before concluding it is Fibonacci(I know few sequences, so it was required).

Comment: I'm not a regular user of this website, and I'm trying to find an answer before posting one. I think the answer lies somewhere between sum of digits and number of prime factors, but I may be totally wrong.

Comment: @VicAche You are completely wrong.

Comment: @awesomepi that's an encouraging comment! I may go back to it then.

Answer (score 0):

How this sequence works:

```
Set your number as A, and set N as zero 

While A is greater than or equal to 2,
Take the prime factorization of A
Add 1 to N and set that as N
Take the greatest prime factor
If it is 2, then break.
If it is greater than 2, set A as the greatest prime factor + 1
End
Put N as the output
```

The answer is **3**

Comment: There's something wrong there, because that loops forever trying to compute the result starting with A=2.  If the line `If it is 2, then set A as 2` is changed to `If it is 2, then break`, then it seems to give the stated results for the fibonacci sequence, but not for some other cases, e.g. 29862968 and 191199.

Comment: So the "hints" $29862968 \to 4$ and $191199 \to 5$ were mistaken? (Your procedure gives $29862968 \to 3$ and $191199 \to 4$.) Here's a trace when $191199$ is input, showing the output is $4$ (not $5$): $$\begin{array}{|c|c||c|} N & A & \rm{gpf}(A) \\
\hline
1&191199&163\\
2&164&41\\
3&42&7\\
\color{blue}{4}&8&\color{red}{2}\\
\end{array}$$
(These are the values of $N,A,$ and $\rm{gpf}(A)$ in each successive pass through the while loop, just after the statement `Take the greatest prime factor`.)